# FTE for Flex 3.6.0?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxmlc

I've got a legacy project which I'm trying to get up and compiling here. Unfortunately, in the process of compiling, it's failing with errors like:

```
Error: Definition flashx.textLayout.elements:TextFlow could not be found.
```

I had thought that FTE was included in the SDK by default. Here's my script by which I'm attempting to compile the application:

```
FLEX_VERSION=3.6.0
FLEX_HOME=/opt/adobe/flex/$FLEX_HOME/

$FLEX_HOME/bin/mxmlc -compiler.source-path+=src \
    -compiler.library-path+=libs \
    -target-player 10.2.0 \ 
    -output bin-release/output.swf \
    src/Application.mxml
```

Pretty straightforward, right? Is there anything I need to do to include the FTE libraries in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to clarify a few things and hope it helps.

The FTE (Flash TExt Engine) is part of the Flash Player / AIR runtimes.  It is not part of the Flex Framework.  To make use of FTE you need to be running / targeting Flash Player 10 or Adobe AIR 1.5.  [Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS6C0BB8ED-2805-467a-9C71-F9D757F33FB6.html)

The [Text Layout Framework](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/) is built on top of the FTE.  It is an ActionScript framework to provide 'advanced' text formatting.  Flex 4 (Spark) components make use of the Text LAyout Framework.  Flex 3 (MX/Halo) components do not.

I doubt that Flex 3.6 [which came out after Flex 4] reworked any of the MX components to use TLF.  As an extension to that, I doubt that Flex 3.6 distributes the Text Layout Framework as part of the SDK.

The compile time error you are seeing relates to the Text Layout Framework.  You could certainly download it from the Adobe web site and add it as a SWF to your project.  But, without seeing the code code you are using; I can't say for certain if that would address your error.

Comment: Right, my bad. I'm going on 25+ hours w/o sleep, so it happens. I just basically compiled the app with Flex 4 and `-compatibility-version=3`.